# Github actions CI/CD cant run shell script

Tags: github, github-actions

Using custom container in a job in github actions ci/cd
In my pack.json I have "plan" script:

> "plan": "./scripts/plan.sh",

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Terraform Plan
    run: |
      npm install
      npm run plan
```

it throws sh: ./scripts/plan.sh: not found

and when I try to run ./scripts/plan.sh in the actions i get

> /__w/_temp/a16e3a71-3c75-4a07-a20e-abe736d546f0.sh: line 2: ./scripts/plan.sh: not found

and this is the container configuration

```
FROM alpine:3.18.0

RUN apk add --no-cache \
  python3 \
  py3-pip \
  terraform \
  nodejs \
  npm \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
  && pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
  awscli \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: Do you have a checkout step in your workflow? Please include rest of your relevant workflow.

Comment: Yes I have checkout

Comment: Right. Where is that `scripts` directory located in your repo? Also, what is that `plan` key above with a trailing comma?

Comment: scripts directory is correct i can run it locally just fine, plan is from package.json

Comment: i ran ls -a and it is in the same directory

Comment: What about that container? Please include its configuration also.

Comment: ok just updated post with configuration

Comment: Are you using [`jobs.<job_id>.container`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) in your workflow?

Comment: The error message from your action lets me suppose that your `plan.sh` should be in `/__w/_temp/scripts/plan.sh` - maybe that's not the case?

Comment: that makes no sense why would it look for at /___w/_temp/? 

and yeah its using jobs.id.container

Comment: Are you building the container in the same workflow? How are you using it? Please include all the relevant parts of your workflow including `container`.

Comment: Also please tell if you're using self hosted runner or not. Double check the working directory at the time of error aligns with your expectation. Document both (your expectation and the real value. if you have no expectation or you're unsure about it, please state that as this is important to communicate on a similar level of understanding).